# ¿Por qué no existe Tang de Hack (lenguaje de programación) en Stackoverflow?

Tags: discusión

¿Por qué no existe la etiqueta del lenguaje de programacion [Hack](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hack_(lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n)) desarrollado en el  2014 por Facebook en Stackoverflow?

Desconozco el lenguaje pero, ¿por qué no existe? o, ¿quizá sea porque es similar a PHP?

Espero que un moderador me pueda contestar.

Comment: No es que sea similar, es una extensión de PHP. No existe porque no ha habido ningún usuario que haya realizado alguna pregunta relacionada con Hack, en mi caso apenas me voy enterando y supongo que al ser una extensión de PHP se hace mención directamente a ese lenguaje.

Comment: Quiza sea una extension de php pero su sintaxis es diferentes lo unico similar son las etiquetas de apertura.

Comment: Sea como sea (extensión, lenguaje, pseudo lenguaje, tecnología, herramienta, etc.), está bien que generes la etiqueta al hacer una pregunta sobre eso... Al crear etiquetas, sólo hay que ser responsable y tener cuidado de no generar meta-etiquetas o una etiqueta con nombre diferente a otra que ya cubre el tema.

Comment: Ok gracias amigo.