# ¿Por qué algunas etiquetas de Stack Overflow no existen en Stack Overflow en español?

Tags: soporte, etiquetas

Viendo Stack Overflow en inglés noté que varias etiquetas que existen ahí no existen en Stack Overflow en español. ¿Por qué es así?

Como ejemplo busqué una (*oracle-apex*) y no me sale. Tampoco me sale alguna opción de sugerir la etiqueta:

[image: y como ejemplo busque una y no me sale, tampoco me sale añguna opcion de sugerir la etiqueta]

cual es el proceso para que una nueva etiqueta sea agregada?, solo es una duda?

Comment: Recientemente has preguntado lo mismo, y te marcaron la pregunta como duplicada y tenía respuesta. [¿Por qué no existe Tang de Hack (lenguaje de programación) en Stackoverflow?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2138/13558). ¿Por qué te importa tanto el motivo de que no existe en el sitio inglés y acá no? Es un sitio independiente, se va formando desde cero.

Comment: no te enojes , solo fue un comentario :)

Comment: Yo iba a marcarla como duplicado de tu otra pregunta, pero veo que la respuesta de Emanuel Ve es bastante clara, con ese screenshot que puso. Entonces la dejo abierta.

Comment: @gilberto me pregunto si realmente lees las respuestas que vas recibiendo a tus preguntas. Esto ya te fue respondido previamente.

Comment: @ArtEze Estás equivocado amigo. **No** es un sitio independiente, StackOverflow no ha abierto fronteras a lo largo del mundo pensando en que serán páginas independientes, todas deben llegar a un mismo objetivo y ese es ayudar a programadores principiantes, intermedios y profesionales, además de las ayudas para encontrar empleo. Es muy molesto que haya gente que diga, que StackOverflow Español es diferente bla bla bla, cuando es realmente lo mismo, lo que cambia es la gente que usa la página, y el idioma. Lo demás es exactamente igual.

Comment: Ahora me doy cuenta que la captura de pantalla no la puso Emanuel Ve, si no que la agregaste tú. Felicidades por tus +4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Las etiquetas se crean al hacer preguntas. Si colocas una etiqueta que no existe (y tienes el [privilegio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) que se obtiene con 300 puntos de reputación), la etiqueta se creará automáticamente.

Es posible que la etiqueta que intentas crear esté en una lista negra y te salga un error similar a este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en el caso normal, la etiqueta es creada con la primera pregunta.

Al crear una nueva etiqueta, ten en cuenta que las etiquetas ...

- No deben tener más de 25 caracteres
- Deben utilizar el conjunto de caracteres `a-z` `áéíóúüñ` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`